# Creating JAX-WS Client to utilize .NET web service (authentication required)

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, endpoint

As I said in headline I am trying to hookup JAVA application to remote web service.  I am pretty new to JAVA and Web Services. I am using Eclipse IDE.

First thing I've done was to run **wsimport** in command window. Provided WSDL url, but got error: **FAILED, Could not find WSDL**. I checked multiple times to make sure that url is correct.

To go around, I saved WSDL locally and thean wsimport didn't have any issues. Moved all generated code to my project and everything seems fine.

Here is my test code

```
// HAVE TO USE PROXY
final String authUser = "xxxxxx";
final String authPassword = "xxxxxx";
String proxyServer = "proxy1.xxxxx.com";
String proxyPort = "99999";

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyServer);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", authUser);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", authPassword);

Authenticator.setDefault(
   new Authenticator() {
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication(authUser, authPassword.toCharArray());
      }
   }
);

WebServiceXX client = new WebServiceXX();
WebServiceXXSoap port = client.getPort(WebServiceXXSoap.class);

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
Map<String, Object> req_ctx = bp.getRequestContext();

req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://domain.com/WebService/WebServiceXX.asmx");
req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");

//HERE, TRYING TO CALL SERVICE. GETTING TIMEOUT ERROR IN 2nd LINE
WebServiceXXSoap service = client.getWebServiceXXSoap();
OperationStatusCodesResp StatusCodes = service.GetOperationStatusCodes();
```

In short, I had to use Proxy server. I tested that part and it seems that is fine.
Since I used local WSDL, I assume that I have to manually set ENDPOINT URL, and since authentication is required, I had to set username and password as you can see it in the code.

The error I am getting is **Time Out Error**.  I am thinking that maybe I didn't set this ENDPOINT properly and that request cannot be made since there is no proper web service url provided.

I tried to edit wsdlLocation in one of the generated java files, to replace local path with real WSDL url, but I am getting error that WSDL can't be found. JAX-WS simply either hate this WSDL or something else is problem. As a note, I didn't have any issues utilizing this service in .NET (C#) application (Web service itself is done in .NET, WSE 2.0)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the reason that my client couldn't load WSDL (https) is because proxy was set for http but not for https. So, I needed to add: System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyServer);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort); into above code

Answer (score 1):

You can try change the `wsdlLocation` of `@WebServiceClient` annotation and the variable `baseUrl` to.

```
https://domain.com/WebService/WebServiceXX.asmx?WSDL
```

For authentication (basic), you can find a good guide in [HTTP basic authentication with JAX-WS (Client)](http://etfdevlab.blogspot.mx/2009/12/http-basic-authentication-with-jax-ws.html).

#### EDIT

You can try Storing the WSDL Locally in your project. For generate the client you can put the WSDL file in a folder, then navigate to the folder using the terminal o symbol system, set the `PATH` for point the `bin` folder of JDK, and use `wsimport` with the local wsdl file.

See an example in [Consuming a Web Service with Java 6 and JAX-WS](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Consuming+a+Web+Service+with+Java+6+and+JAX-WS) - Wiki - Confluence.

Then you can use the way in the *Specifying the Endpoint Address and HTTP Basic Authorization* section.

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing wsdlLocation. I would get error message that WSDL can't be found. Also, when I use wsimport and when I provide WSDL url, I get message that url doesn't exist. I tried to use Putty to connect to this location and I get same error "Host does not exist". Firewall?

Comment: ok, the part where my wsimport can't read WSDL url is a proxy issue. I am trying to figure out now how to set proxy in command prompt. But, this still doesn't explain why java code times out when I set proxy and when I define web service endpoint.

Comment: Your last link - my proxy server requires authentication. There is no way to provide username and pass to wsimport. Tried -httpproxy:user:pass@host:port, it didn't work.